# how to upload data to mongodb in streamlit app

Tags: python, mongodb, streamlit

unable to insert dataframe to mongoDB through streamlit app,
atlas is used as data base. no errors popped up. app get terminated while upload function starts.
Here is the code

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import pymongo
from tscrape import scrape_twitter_data

# Connect to MongoDB
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://PriyabrataDS:<Password>@cluster1.j9x92do.mongodb.net/test")
db = client['trial']
test = db['Test']

# Define a function to upload data to MongoDB
def upload_to_mongodb(data):
    # Insert data into MongoDB
    result = test.insert_many(data.to_dict('records'))
    # Display result
    st.write(f'{len(result.inserted_ids)} documents uploaded to MongoDB')
    return result


# Define the Streamlit app
def main():
    # Page title
    st.title('Twitter Scraper')

    # Get user input
    hashtag = st.text_input('Hashtag/Keyword')
    start_date = st.date_input('Start Date')
    end_date = st.date_input('End Date')
    max_tweets = st.number_input('Max Tweets')

    # Scrape Twitter data
    if st.button('Scrape'):
        tweets_df = scrape_twitter_data(hashtag, start_date, end_date, max_tweets)

        # Display data in a table
        st.write(tweets_df)

        # Upload data to MongoDB
        if st.button('Upload to MongoDB'):
            # Upload data to MongoDB
            upload_to_mongodb(tweets_df)
            st.success('Data uploaded to MongoDB.')

            # Display the uploaded data in a table
            st.write(pd.DataFrame(list(test.find())))

        # Download data in CSV format
        st.download_button('Download CSV',
                           tweets_df.to_csv(),
                           file_name='twitter_scrape.csv',
                           mime="text/csv")

        # Download data in JSON format
        st.download_button('Download JSON',
                           tweets_df.to_json(),
                           file_name='twitter_scrape.json',
                           mime="text/json")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

i tried twitter scraping using snscrape and present it through streamlit app.

just want to upload the scraped data to mongodb database.. that's it

Comment: You're currently connecting to a local instance, not altas

Comment: i tried even with atlas still can't get anywhere